# Unstructured quad mesh-generation?

Tags: mesh-generation, computational-geometry

What is the best (scalability and efficiency) algorithms for generating unstructured quad meshes in 2D?

Where can I find a good unstructured quad mesh-generator? (open-source preferred)

Comment: Tsk. A tip: when creating a multi-word tag, please use dashes to separate out the words.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The are essentially two approaches to free quad meshing:

- **Direct** methods generate a quad mesh directly, usually by some advancing front method. The [Paving paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/nme.1620320410) is a standard reference and is the method used by [CUBIT](http://cubit.sandia.gov), so you have seen these meshes in many publications.
- **Indirect** methods generate some intermediate decomposition of the domain (e.g. triangles) and then produce an all-quad mesh through recombination and/or further decomposition. [Q-Morph](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ecsverma/CS899_09/qmorph.pdf) is an example that is used by ANSYS.

Note that smoothing is necessary for both approaches, sometimes with alternating topology fix-up and smoothing steps. Some open source tools have built-in smoothing facilities and the LGPL-licensed [Mesquite](http://www.cs.sandia.gov/optimization/knupp/Mesquite.html) package is designed as a library specifically for mesh quality improvement.

I know of two open source free-quad meshers:

- [**Gmsh**](http://geuz.org/gmsh/) (GPL with linking exception) can generate quad meshes using a recombination algorithm described in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-24734-7_25).
- The **Jaal** component of [MeshKit](http://trac.mcs.anl.gov/projects/fathom/wiki/MeshKit) (LGPL) is based on recombination similar to Q-Morph above, read [the IMR-2011 paper](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ecsverma/imr11.pdf) for more details. You can download the source through the link above, but it is not ready for production use yet.
- [**LBIE**](http://ccvweb.csres.utexas.edu/cvc/projects/project.php?pageIndex=1&proID=10) generates quad and hex meshes from volumetric data. From what I can tell, it is an interactive environment rather than a library. The site says that the source is available under GPL upon request.
- [**CUBIT**](http://cubit.sandia.gov) is not open source (and although not expensive compared to commercial software, acquiring a license takes a long time), but produces high quality meshes and can be linked into other applications.

Comment: I have learned that Gmsh (http://geuz.org/gmsh/) now also has support for unstructured 2D quad generation by some ”Blossom” recombination algorithm.

Comment: Is there a similar method for 3D hexahedrons?

Comment: Hex meshes are usually done by sweeping quad meshes and then smoothing (robust, but have to decompose domains). You can also create hex meshes by recombination using H-Morph (Owen and Saigal, 2000; http://www.osti.gov/energycitations/servlets/purl/756062-uQ2PGj/webviewable/756062.pdf), a method similar to Q-Morph referenced above, but it is difficult to maintain quality.

Comment: Yes, gmsh has supported quads for a while now.

Comment: This answer is about two years old now and I believe this is still a very pertinent question. Has there been significant evolution on unstructured quad and especially hex  meshing? I was wondering if there were any new software (commercial or open source) which allow for 3D unstructured hex meshing. I know gmsh can do 3D hex by extruding 2D quads, but i'm looking for something more appropriate for complex geometries.

Comment: @BlaB No revolution in the past seven years. Unstructured hex meshing of complicated geometry is still labor-intensive and/or has quality challenges (see H-Morph).

Answer (score 1):

1. It would be great if gmsh would further include mesquite as 3rd party.
2. I am from the engineering field, where structured grid is possible and strongly advised.
3. CUBIT seems to be the mesquite's professional version, or commercial version.
4. mesquite project ended a few year ago, though some other guys seems to continue keep it going. (meshkit?)
5. I have a very very good GUI experience with gmsh, it's easy going, light weighted, etc.!